# ImportError: No module named bs4 while running in terminal

Tags: visual-studio, beautifulsoup, terminal, importerror

I am trying to run a python script via terminal but keep receiving the following error:

```
'''
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "note9.py", line 1, in <module>
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ImportError: No module named bs4
'''
```

I have tried uninstalling bs4 and reinstalling bs4.

The weird thing is that I am able to run the script in visual studio code.

```
'''
User:PythonProjects username$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/username/Desktop/PythonProjects/note9.py
Unavailable
'''
```

Why am I receiving the error message when trying to run the script via terminal?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
import yagmail 

def lovely_soup(u):
    r = get(u, headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1'})
    return BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')


url = 'https://www.baka.ca/Samsung/Samsung-Galaxy-Note-9-128GB-LTE-Blue'
soup = lovely_soup(url)
for h2 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    if 'Unavailable' in h2.text:
        yagmail.SMTP('mygmailusername').send('to@someone.com', 'subject', contents)    
        print('Unavailable')
    else:
        yagmail.SMTP('mygmailusername').send('to@someone.com', 'subject', contents)
        print('Available')
```

'''

The following is the error I receive when running in the terminal

```
Tylers-MacBook-Air-2:PythonProjects tylerarie$ python note9.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "note9.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
Tylers-MacBook-Air-2:PythonProjects tylerarie$ pip3 install bs4
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from bs4) (4.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (1.9.5)
Tylers-MacBook-Air-2:PythonProjects tylerarie$
```

It does say that the module is already installed? Why can't I run this script in the terminal!!??

The script runs perfectly fine in VSC.

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Tylers-MacBook-Air-2:PythonProjects tylerarie$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/tylerarie/Desktop/PythonProjects/note9.py
Unavailable
Tylers-MacBook-Air-2:PythonProjects tylerarie$
```

Comment: Can you run any other script from the terminal? how are you running from the terminal?

Comment: I am able to run other scripts, yes, but I only have this one script with import bs4. I navigate to the directory where the .py file Is stored and run the command: python filename.py

Comment: okay can you post your script

Comment: are you able to see the script in my post - I am new to StackOverflow, first post! Thanks a lot for the quick responses and your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: added my script to my post as well as the terminal errors I receive when trying to run the script.  It says that bs4 is already installed - I'm so baffled as to why this is not running? I also added what happens when I run is VSC to show that it's working there.